# How can I change text navigation and deletion key combinations in PowerPoint 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

As [Wikipedia lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing) and my experience tells me, most applications on Mac OSX use <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Delete left</kbd>) to delete a word to the left and fewer, but still many, use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete left</kbd>) to delete everything to the beginning of the line.

Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac 2011, however, breaks the pattern: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> does nothing. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> does take me to the beginning of the line, but <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> deletes one word to the left. Word for Mac 2011 had the same problem, but I managed to change the shortcuts via *Tools > Customize Keyboard...*.

Application specific shortcuts set via the *System Preferences* do not include text editing commands as far as I can see, so that did not help me.

Is there any other way to make text deletion commands work in PowerPoint like they do for other applications?